Expo Build Problem - Unsupported MIME type: image/webp
I'm getting the following errors when building my Expo project for iOS and Android. I'm not using any .webp files anywhere in my project. However, I haven't been able to solve the problem. What do you think could be the issue?
"expo": "^50.0.0",
"react": "18.2.0",
"react-native": "0.73.6",

IOS
- Creating native directory (./ios)
✔ Created native directory
- Updating package.json
✔ Updated package.json
- Running prebuild
✖ Prebuild failed
Error: [ios.dangerous]: withIosDangerousBaseMod: Unsupported MIME type: image/webp
Error: [ios.dangerous]: withIosDangerousBaseMod: Unsupported MIME type: image/webp
    at Jimp.throwError (/Users/expo/workingdir/build/node_modules/jimp-compact/dist/jimp.js:1:833)
    at Jimp.parseBitmap (/Users/expo/workingdir/build/node_modules/jimp-compact/dist/jimp.js:1:125733)
    at Jimp.parseBitmap (/Users/expo/workingdir/build/node_modules/jimp-compact/dist/jimp.js:1:8514)
    at /Users/expo/workingdir/build/node_modules/jimp-compact/dist/jimp.js:1:7613
    at FSReqCallback.readFileAfterClose [as oncomplete] (node:internal/fs/read_file_context:68:3)
npx expo prebuild --no-install --platform ios exited with non-zero code: 1

ANDROID
- Creating native directory (./android)
✔ Created native directory
- Updating package.json
✔ Updated package.json
- Running prebuild
✖ Prebuild failed
Error: [android.dangerous]: withAndroidDangerousBaseMod: Unsupported MIME type: image/webp
Error: [android.dangerous]: withAndroidDangerousBaseMod: Unsupported MIME type: image/webp
    at Jimp.throwError (/home/expo/workingdir/build/node_modules/jimp-compact/dist/jimp.js:1:833)
    at Jimp.parseBitmap (/home/expo/workingdir/build/node_modules/jimp-compact/dist/jimp.js:1:125733)
    at Jimp.parseBitmap (/home/expo/workingdir/build/node_modules/jimp-compact/dist/jimp.js:1:8514)
    at /home/expo/workingdir/build/node_modules/jimp-compact/dist/jimp.js:1:7613
    at FSReqCallback.readFileAfterClose [as oncomplete] (node:internal/fs/read_file_context:68:3)
npx expo prebuild --no-install --platform android exited with non-zero code: 1


Resolve: compileSdkVersion -> 34, compileSdkVersion -> 34

If u have custom image in ur app.json > "icon": yourimage.png, get back to the original one "icon": "./assets/icon.png", that fixed it for me

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
